# How to make a fxml layout resizible

Tags: java, javafx, layout

I have a one page java fx application and i want to make the layout resizible but i don' know how.
This is the code :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<GridPane fx:id="home" alignment="center" gridLinesVisible="true" hgap="10" vgap="10"
          xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.112" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
          fx:controller="sample.Controller">

    <AnchorPane prefHeight="748.0" prefWidth="1360.0" styleClass="section2">
        <AnchorPane layoutX="0.0" layoutY="40.0" prefHeight="768.0" prefWidth="1359.0">
            <children>
                <Button layoutX="37.0" layoutY="281.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ReadMainData"
                        prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="171.0" styleClass="sectionRead" text="Read Main Data"/>
                <Button layoutX="37.0" layoutY="316.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ReadStructural"
                        prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="171.0" styleClass="sectionRead" text="Read Mass Properties"/>
                <Button layoutX="37.0" layoutY="384.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ReadNumParts"
                        prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="171.0" styleClass="sectionRead" text="Read Part List"/>
                <Button layoutX="37.0" layoutY="572.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#WriteIdentification"
                        prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="171.0" styleClass="sectionWrite" text="Write Main Data"/>
                <Button layoutX="37.0" layoutY="609.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#WriteMassProperty"
                        prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="171.0" styleClass="sectionWrite" text="Write Mass Properties"/>
                <Button layoutX="37.0" layoutY="678.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#WriteNumParts"
                        prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="171.0" styleClass="sectionWrite" text="Write Part List"/>
                <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="52.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="106.0"
                       text="choose the port"/>
                <ChoiceBox fx:id="choice" accessibleText="Choice" layoutX="60.0" layoutY="64.0"
                           onMousePressed="#fillComboBox" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="89.0">

                    <items>

                    </items>

                </ChoiceBox>

                <AnchorPane fx:id="paneSample" layoutX="260.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1096.0"
                            styleClass="section1"/>


                <Label fx:id="sampleVisualizzaId" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="42.0" layoutY="114.0" prefHeight="33.0"
                       prefWidth="125.0" text="ID"/>
                <Button fx:id="readId" layoutX="60.0" layoutY="179.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#getUid"
                        prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="89.0" text="Get ID"/>
                <ImageView fitHeight="62.0" fitWidth="60.0" layoutX="84.0" layoutY="467.0" pickOnBounds="true"
                           preserveRatio="true">
                    <image>
                        <Image url="/sample/g logo.png"/>
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
                <Button layoutX="37.0" layoutY="348.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ReadGeometricProperties"
                        prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="171.0" styleClass="sectionRead" text="Read Geometric Properties"/>


                <Button layoutX="37.0" layoutY="644.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#WriteBasic" prefHeight="25.0"
                        prefWidth="171.0" styleClass="sectionWrite" text="Write Geometric Properties"/>


            </children>
        </AnchorPane>


    </AnchorPane>

</GridPane>
```

How you see the layout is maded by two anchor pane in which. The layout is a master detail layout.When the user push on of the button the program update the second anchor pane with the specific layout for the app.
The application work fine but i want to make it resizible thanks for help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few things to take care of even in fxml.

1. ChoiceBox does not have attribute "accessibleText", so it does not even open in scene builder. How can we help if your code does not compile/open?
2. First rule of any good design - do not use tables (Gridpanes) for layout. It applies in WEB/HTML, it applies here too. There are plenty great controls/containers you can use. I always prefer to start with AnchorPane, others prefer BorderPane, HPane, VPane or Pane also seem like great choices. I have replaced your root element with AnchorPane. Tables are for tabulated data or layout where you have many repetitive elements side by side.

Then start filling out your layout based on your needs - you clearly have two elements side by side, so HPane works best, then the left pane is just vertical list of buttons, etc.. so use VPane, and so on...

3. Try to limit the use of layoutY and layoutX - you fix your elements to certain positions on the screen, but as soon as you start resizing your window, bad things will happen... VBox for example has `spacing="20.0"` which nicely spaces all elements on the pane all you have to do is 'throw them in a bucket' in the right order
4. If you want element/container/pane to resize when you resize your window - the best option you have is to tie it to the window's edge - use `AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0"` and  margins like `<HBox.margin><Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" /></HBox.margin>`, also look at and for things like `HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"` which allows your panes to resize with the window.

Take care of your code, make it simple and usable, understandable, and it will take care of you... it will be much easier to modify.

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    
    <?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
    <?import javafx.geometry.*?>
    <?import java.lang.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
    <?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
    
    <AnchorPane fx:id="home" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller" styleClass="section2" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <children>
            <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
               <children>
                  <VBox fillWidth="false" prefHeight="1000.0" prefWidth="200.0" spacing="20.0" HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
                     <children>
                      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ReadMainData" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="171.0" styleClass="sectionRead" text="Read Main Data" />
                      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ReadStructural" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="171.0" styleClass="sectionRead" text="Read Mass Properties" />
                      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ReadNumParts" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="171.0" styleClass="sectionRead" text="Read Part List" />
                      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#WriteIdentification" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="171.0" styleClass="sectionWrite" text="Write Main Data" />
                      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#WriteMassProperty" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="171.0" styleClass="sectionWrite" text="Write Mass Properties" />
                      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#WriteNumParts" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="171.0" styleClass="sectionWrite" text="Write Part List" />
                      <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="106.0" text="choose the port" />
                      <ChoiceBox fx:id="choice" onMousePressed="#fillComboBox" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="89.0">
                        <items>
         </items>
                      </ChoiceBox>
                      <Label fx:id="sampleVisualizzaId" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="125.0" text="ID" />
                      <Button fx:id="readId" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#getUid" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="89.0" text="Get ID" />
                      <ImageView fitHeight="62.0" fitWidth="60.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                          <image>
                              <Image url="/sample/g logo.png" />
                          </image>
                      </ImageView>
                      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ReadGeometricProperties" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="171.0" styleClass="sectionRead" text="Read Geometric Properties" />
                      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#WriteBasic" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="171.0" styleClass="sectionWrite" text="Write Geometric Properties" />
                  </children>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" top="20.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </VBox>
                  <AnchorPane fx:id="paneSample" prefHeight="1000.0" styleClass="section1" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                     <children>
                        <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                     </children></AnchorPane>
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </children>
    </AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Thanks it is a almost complete answer to my question, almost because i must find the perfect answer by myself with your big help.